# Qual é a melhor forma de converter entidades HTML com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Através de pesquisas no SO inglês, aprendi a fazer decodificação e codificação de entidades HTML da seguinte forma:

```
var wm = (function(wm){ 
   wm.encodeHTML = function (html) {
        var t = document.createElement('textarea');
        t.innerHTML = html;
        return t.innerHTML;
   }    
   wm.decodeHTML = function (html) {
        var t = document.createElement('textarea');
        t.innerHTML = html;    
        return t.value;
   }       
}({}));
```

Eu gostaria de uma solução mais elegante (expressão regular ou qualquer outra coisa) para converter entidades HTML, ao invés de criar um `textarea` e retornar o valor dele.

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Por acaso algo como isso? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229518/javascript-regex-replace-html-chars

Comment: Olha "mais elegante" não seria um caminho e `RegEx` pode ajudar muito, mas não serve para todos objetivos, no seu próprio exemplo você usou DOM (`createElement`) isto é totalmente aceitável, pois entidades html também fazem parte do `DOM`, e acredite o seu código terá bem aceitável ("talvez" melhor do qualquer outra técnica). Portanto de *entidade html* fazem parte do DOM, não vejo mal em usar o próprio `DOM` para convertê-las. Outra coisa, da maneira que você fez o código fica bem menor e na minha opinião é a **indentação** combinado com códigos pequenos e organizados que farão a elegância :)

Comment: Só outro detalhe Wallace, a sua função `wm.decodeHTML = function (html) {` não está fechada, falta um `}` após o `return`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu uso duas funções que achei na internet, faça um teste:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery
function htmlEncode(value) {
    //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
    //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
    return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value) {
    return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}
```

Ou como o autor preferiu com RegEx:

```
var replaceHtmlEntites = (function() {
    var translate_re = /&(nbsp|amp|quot|lt|gt);/g,
        translate = {
            'nbsp': String.fromCharCode(160), 
            'amp' : '&', 
            'quot': '"',
            'lt'  : '<', 
            'gt'  : '>'
        },
        translator = function($0, $1) { 
            return translate[$1]; 
        };

    return function(s) {
        return s.replace(translate_re, translator);
    };
})();
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229518/javascript-regex-replace-html-chars

Comment: É a mesma coisa que eu fiz, porém com `jQuery`. Estou a procura de outras soluções (como regex por exemplo)

Comment: Não entendo a negativação, pois você mesmo disse "...regexp ou qualquer outra coisa" (MAXTERS, 2015).

Comment: Eu também não vejo necessidade deste voto negativo, soa até meio mal, mas acho que é porque você postou um código já com a mesma funcionalidade e ele pediu algo com `RegEx` ao invés de criar um `textarea` (no caso ele deve ter se referido ao uso de DOM). Acho que você deveria apenas editar a resposta :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado, fiz exatamente isso! :)

Comment: Só uma coisa para ajudar Rafael, a segunda função só "decodifica", acho que o autor necessita de ambos. :) Mas mesmo assim +1

Comment: Retirei o -1 visto que a resposta foi alterada. Muito bom! parece um pouquinho com o código-fonte do underscore :)

Comment: Sim, precisaria de uma pequena adaptação para o caso inverso; mas acredito que já seja um passo positivo para a solução que o autor gostaria; Obrigado Guilherme e Wallace.

Answer (score 3):

Não entendi muito bem mas oque você esta tentando fazer é transformar html em text e text em html? porque se for tem esse jeito usando replace.

```
var string="<div>oi</div>";
string.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;"); // &ld;div&gd;oi&ld;/div&gd;
```

E para voltar pro html:

```
var string="&ld;div&gd;oi&ld;/div&gd";
string.replace(/&lt;/g,"<").replace(/&gt;/g,">"); // <div>oi</div>
```

Comment: Sua função está errada. Não é `&ld;` é `&lt;` :)

Comment: Obrigado por essa observação @gui ;)....

Answer (score 1):

Pode-se fazer assim também (código retirado do [*mustache.js*](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/blob/master/mustache.js#L52)):

```
var entityMap = { // Lista de entidades
    "&": "&amp;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;',
    "/": '&#x2F;'
};

function escapeHtml(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function (s) {
    return entityMap[s];
  });
}
```

A expressão `[&<>"'\/]` vai corresponder a qualquer caractere presente na lista `&<>"'\/`, se o *replace* tiver êxito será retornado através de `entityMap` o valor convertido.

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nbe9n12u/)</kbd>

Para fazer o caminho reverso basta inverter a ordem da lista e a expressão:

```
var entityMap = { // Lista de entidades
    '&amp;': '&',
    '&lt;': '<',
    '&gt;': '>',
    '&quot': '"',
    '&#39;': "'",
    '&#x2F;': '/'
};

function unescapeHtml(str) {
  return String(str).replace(/&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|&quot|&#39;|&#x2F;/g, function (s) {
    return entityMap[s];
  });
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6dyf1ab/)</kbd>