# Como escrever HTML como texto dentro de uma div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Por exemplo tenho a div:

`<div class="option" id="resposta-1" onclick="mudaConteudo()"></div>`

Gostaria de escrever sem que o html reconhecesse como uma tag mas sim um texto:

`<div class="option" id="resposta-1" onclick="mudaConteudo()"><title></title></div>`

Porem não encontrei nenhuma forma de converter a tag  em texto

Comment: É isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49756/112052

Comment: Talvez a resposta do itasouza resolva o problema. Porém, acredito que seja duplicada de: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59934/como-escrever-c%C3%B3digos-como-exemplo-sem-executar

Comment: Aqui no fórum, as perguntas são negativas quando são muito simples ou por diversos outros motivos, para você que está começando, talvez seja bom ter mais opções de consulta, antes de fazer uma pergunta

Answer (score 10):

Como você quer mudar o conteúdo de uma *`<div>`* de HTML para texto pode usar a função abaixo:

> O código abaixo está verificando o atributo `data-content` para mudar de HTML para texto ou vice-versa.

```js
function mudaConteudo(){
  var area=document.getElementById("area");
  
  if (area.dataset.content == "html") {
    area.innerText = area.innerHTML;
    area.dataset.content = "text";
  } else {
    area.innerHTML = area.innerText;
    area.dataset.content = "html";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="area" data-content="html" ><h1>Alou!</h1></div>
<button onclick="mudaConteudo()">Muda Conteúdo</button>
```

Assim como o @AugustoVasques falou no comentário da resposta do @itasouza `innerHTML` irá transformar o texto em HTML, para que o texto não seja renderizado como HTML deve utilizar `innerText`.

Segue exemplo

```js
var content = "<h1>Alou!</h1>"
var area = document.getElementById('area');

function addTexto(){
  area.innerText = content;
}

function addHTML(){
  area.innerHTML = content;
}
```

```html
<div id="area"></div>
<button onclick="addTexto()">Adiciona Texto</button>
<button onclick="addHTML()">Adiciona HTML</button>
```

Answer (score 6):

Como vc colocou tag CSS na pergunta vou te dar uma resposta só com CSS.

Todo o conteúdo que vc coloca dentro de um `content:` de um *pseudo-elemento* é renderizado como texto e não como código, pois ele é um conteúdo que não existe no DOM do HTML, ele é construído no CSS.

Veja o exemplo e cloquei no `checkbox`.

```css
input:checked + div::after {
    content: "<h1>minha tag</h1>"
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">exibir tag
<div></div>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Vc tb pode escrever seu HTML direto em um *custom attribute* direto na tag (ex: `<div data-html="<h1>meu h1</h1>">`), depois vc pode usar um *pseudo elemento* com `content:attr(data-html)` para pegar o que está em `data-html=""` e colocar na tela.

```css
input:checked + div::after {
    content: attr(data-html);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="" id="">exibir tag
<div data-html="<h1>meu h1</h1>"></div>
```

**OBS1:** Fiz esse exemplo da forma mais simples possível apenas para fins didáticos

**OBS2:** O inconveniente dessa técnica é que como o texto não está no DOM vc não consegue seleciona-lo para por exemplo dar um `Ctrl+C / Ctrl + V`

Answer (score 5):

Veja se isso ajuda na solução:

```
<script>
function mudaConteudo() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<p>Outro texto</p>";
}
</script>

<p id="demo" onclick="mudaConteudo()">Usando (innerHTML).</p>
```

Comment: Acho que se usar a propriedade `innerText` ao invés de `innerHTML` responde a pergunta:
`document.getElementById("demo").innerText= "<p>Outro texto</p>"`

Comment: @AugustoVasques, talvez seja uma opção, o Leonardo deve testar e ver o que atende, eu fiquei surpreso agora, porque uma pergunta simples, vários tentaram ajudar sem ter nenhuma negativa